# Homology with Coefficients

Tags: graph-theory, at.algebraic-topology, homology

We can define the (first) homology of a surface $S$ by working with graphs embedded in $S$.  That is, we take any (oriented) graph which is 2-cell embedded in $S$, and take cycles modulo boundaries in the usual way.  Here, I am talking about homology with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$.  The group that we get is independent of the graph, so is indeed a topological invariant of the surface.

I work with *group-labelled graphs*, which are oriented graphs with their edges labelled from a finite abelian group $\Gamma$.  Proceeding as above, group-labelled graphs allow us to define *group-labelled surfaces*.  That is, let $G$ be a $\Gamma$-labelled graph 2-cell embedded in a surface $S$.  If each face of the embedding has group-value zero (the labels of edges on the boundary of the face sum to zero), then this gives a well-defined map on homology.  In fact, the embedding of $G$ in S induces a homomorphism from $H_1(S)$ to $\Gamma$.   So, we can forget about the $\Gamma$-labelled graph and just study this homomorphism.

**My question is:** how does this construction relate to taking homology with coefficients from $\Gamma$?

Someone once told me that what I am really doing is working with *cohomology* with coefficients in $\Gamma$, but I didn't really get this. Can someone please clarify?

Comment: Depending on how you make your labelling precise it sounds like you're either talking about plain-old cellular cohomology with coefficients (see for example Bredon or Hatcher's books), or you're perhaps taking a further step and looking at cellular cohomology with local coefficients.  Hatcher's book covers both ideas in detail. 

Comment: Sorry if I was imprecise, but the only restriction on the group-labelling is that each face has group-value zero.  I guess my question is that there are two ways to 'mod out' by the group $\Gamma$.  One is to work with $\Gamma$-labelled graphs satisfying the face condition.  This leads to homomorphisms from $H_1(S)$ into $\Gamma$.  The second is to work with coefficients in $\Gamma$, either in homology or cohomology.  I was wondering how the two notions are related.  Thanks for the links everyone. 

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, what does "2-cell embedded" mean?

Comment: 2-cell embedded means that every face is a disk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi Tony.

This is not really a homology-question, the core of it is the fundamental group. The homomorphism you are using is used in the study of [Van Kampen diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Kampen_diagram). Consider a presentation $G=\langle A|R\rangle$. A Van Kampen diagram on $S$ is a labeled graph like you have defined it. The only difference is that in a Van Kampen diagram all labels are generators (or their inverses) $a^{\pm 1}$ and not arbitrary words (although you could define it in this general way without problems because of the Van Kampen lemma).

Then every path in this graph has a group word written on it and "reading the word along a path" is a homomorphism {Paths}$\to G$ with respect to composition of paths. It turns out, that this is compatible with homotopy of paths so this induces a homomorphism $\pi_1(S,x_0)\to G$.

This is the general version of your homomorphism: If your $G$ happens to be abelian, then this homomorphism factorizes through $\pi_1(S,x_0)^{ab}$ which is $H_1(S)$ by the Hurewicz theorem.

This point of view clarifies some connections between the geometry of Van Kampen diagrams and group theoretic questions.

For example the Van Kampen lemma tells you that a group word is trivial if and only if there is a Van Kampen diagram on this disk with this word written on the boundary.

Another fact is this one: If there are no nontrivial "reduced" Van Kampen diagrams on the torus, then every two commuting elements of $G$ generate a cyclic subgroup (i.e. $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}=1$ has only the trivial solutions $x=a^k, y=a^m$ for some $a\in G$.). In a similar spirit one can prove: If there are no nontrivial reduced Van Kampen diagrams on the real projective plane, then there are no involutions in $G$ (i.e. $x^2=1$ has only the trivial solution $x=1$), and if there are no nontrivial reduced Van Kampen diagrams on Klein's bottle, then the only element that is conjugated to its own inverse is the identity (i.e. $yxy^{-1}=x^{-1}$ has only the trivial solution $x=1$).

This connection between geometry and group properties becomes less obscure, if one knows the fundamental groups of the disk (1), the torus ($\langle x,y | xyx^{-1}y^{-1}=1\rangle$), the real projective plane ($\langle x | x^2=1\rangle$) and Klein's bottle ($\langle x,y | yxy^{-1}=x^{-1}\rangle$).

Comment: Hi Johannes. Thanks for the response. I was wondering if this is indeed a question about homotopy rather than homology. For example, if I take $\Gamma=\pi_1 (S, x_0)$, then there should be a $\Gamma$-labelling of the graph $G$ so that each cycle in $G$ containing $x_0$  has group-value precisely its homotopy class. I can see this if I take $\Gamma =H_1(S)$, since I can just label each edge of a spanning tree $T$ of $G$ zero, and each non-tree edge $e$ with the homology class of the unique cycle in $T \cup e$. Since these cycles generate the homology, this works. 

Answer (score 3):

Browsing a good introduction to algebraic topology up to the [Universal coefficient theorem for cohomology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_coefficient_theorem#Universal_coefficient_theorem_for_cohomology) would be a good plan. Hatcher's book, which you can get online, for example.

Comment: May's book is also available online on his website if you're not as interested in the geometric aspects of AT.  

Answer (score 2):

The reason that this is *cohomology* and not *homology* is that you are looking at functions from the cells to the group.

Comment: Perhaps I should be more explicit about the function that I am describing.  It is a function $h$ from the closed walks (cycles) of the group-labelled graph $G$ into the group $\Gamma$.  Explicitly, $h$ maps a cycle $C$ to the (oriented) sum of the group-labels of the edges of $C$. With the condition that all faces of $G$ have group-value zero, this map becomes well-defined on homology. Let $C_1$ and $C_2$ be homologous.  Then, $C_1 \cup C_2$ is the boundary of an orientable component of $S - C_1 \cup C_2$.  Since each face of $G$ has group-value zero, we have $h(C_1)-h(C_2)=0$, as required.  